# How do I save values and write them to an external csv file during a load test in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter-4.0

How do I save values and write them to an external csv file during a load test in Jmeter.

Can someone help me please.

Answer (score 0):

```
name = vars.get("name");
email = vars.get("email");

log.info(email);    

// if you want to log something to jmeter.log file

// Pass true if you want to append to existing file
// If you want to overwrite, then don't pass the second argument

f = new FileOutputStream("/my/file/path/result.csv", true);
p = new PrintStream(f); 
this.interpreter.setOut(p); 
print(name + "," + email);
f.close();
```